# php Notice : Array to string conversion in

Tags: php, arrays

I've the following array`$_SESSION['survey_ans'][]=$records;`
and will get the result with`var_dump($_SESSION['survey_ans']);`

```
array(6) {
    [0]=> array(1) {
        [1]=> string(5) "vpoor" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(1) { 
        [10]=> string(4) "poor" 
    } 
    [2]=> array(1) { 
        [6]=> string(7) "average" 
    } 
    [3]=> array(1) { 
        [11]=> string(4) "good" 
    } 
    [4]=> array(1) { 
        [12]=> string(5) "vgood" 
    } 
    [5]=> array(1) { 
        [13]=> string(4) "good" 
    } 
}
```

But when I run this

```
foreach($_SESSION['survey_ans'] as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key."-".$value."<br />";
}
```

I will get the error "Notice : Array to string conversion in ".  So how do I get the result as following?

```
1, vpoor
10, poor
6, average
11, good
12, vgood
13, good
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements of `$_SESSION['survey_ans']` are arrays, so you need to iterate through the values in each array to get your desired output. Try this:

```
foreach($_SESSION['survey_ans'] as $result) {
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        echo $key."-".$value."<br />";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1-vpoor
10-poor
6-average
11-good
12-vgood
13-good
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/CJrot)

Comment: When i put 0 and i got the following error?Notice : Undefined offset: 0

Comment: why would it be `$value[0]`, when they are `[1]=> string(5) ...`,`[10]=> string(4) ...`, `[6]=> string(7) ...`, etc?

Comment: I got the result as below but not the expected one??0-vpoor
1-poor
2-average
3-good
4-vgood
5-good

Comment: thanks for everyone for the valuable knowledge to me.